# IVP of second order linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Bumps are often built into roads to discourage speeding. Consider a
>   crude model of the vertical motion $y(t)$ of a car encountering the
>   speed bump with the speed $V$ is given by $$y(t)=0   \qquad\text{for}\;
>  t \leq -L/(2V)$$ $$my''+ky= \begin{cases} F_0\cos(\pi Vt/L) & 
>  \text{for}\, |t|<L/(2V)\\ 0                          & \text{for}\,t
>  \geq L/(2V) \end{cases}$$ Taking $m=k=1, L=\pi,$ and $F_0 =1$ in
>   appropriate units, solve $y(t)$.

It reduces to solving $y''+y=\cos(Vt)$. The usual method of undetermined coefficients applies and I get the following, which check with that from Wolfram Alpha:
$$y(t)= \begin{cases} \frac{\cos(Vt)}{1-V^2}+A \cos t + B\sin t &
 \text{if}\, V \neq 1\\ \frac{t \sin t}{2} +A \cos t + B\sin t         &
\text{if}\,V = 1 \end{cases}.$$

When I check the solution provided by the book, I find this:
$$y(t)= \begin{cases} \frac{2V \cos (\pi / 2V)}{V^2-1} \sin t &
 \text{if}\, V \neq 1\\ \frac{\pi}{2} \sin t         &
\text{if}\,V = 1 \end{cases}.$$

I cannot proceed to find these solutions. I tried substituting $t=-\frac{\pi}{2V}$, but I have two unknowns. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the  solution you have is valid only in $-\pi/2V < t < \pi/2V$

at $t = -\pi/2V, y$ is continuous  gives you 
$$A \cos \pi/2V - B \sin \pi/2V = 0  \tag 1$$

the condition $y^\prime$  is continuous at $t = -\pi/2V$ gives you 
$$ A\sin \pi/2V + B \cos \pi/2V = \dfrac{V}{1-V^2}\tag 2$$ 
solve the two equation for $A, B.$

i guess the effect of the bump persists. therefore for $t > \pi/2V,$ the solution is of the form $$y = C\cos t + D \sin t $$ do the matching at $t = \pi/2V$ of both $y$ and $y^\prime$ with the previous solution.

you can do the case $V=1$ in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried but it becomes $$y(t) = \frac{\cos (Vt)}{1-v^2} + \frac{v}{v^2-1}\sin (\pi / 2V) \cos t + \frac{v}{v^2 - 1} \cos (\pi / 2V) \sin t.$$
What to do next lol

Comment: If so, how do I amend my solution to find $y(t)$ for $t > \pi/2V$?

Comment: @LeeKM, i have added some more stuff.

Comment: Although tedious, I finally get the correct answer!Thanks for your help:)